# Load terraform module from local path which can be set as a environment variable

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform module in my local "tmp\module\vpc".
Is there any way this local path "tmp\module\vpc" can be set in a environment variable and use it in the "source" field of calling module.

module "vpc" {

**source  = "/tmp/modules/vpc"**

vpcname   = var.vpcname

}

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Dynamic module paths is not something terraform supports.